# Create a result set that combines the results from several queries in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my scenario: I have two different tables: 
Table 'subscriptions' contains all the information related to subscriptions to user sites, and the 'ratings' table, which contains scores to products of subscribing sites. Simplifying is something like that:

```
Subscriptions: 'id','user','place','created', etc.
Ratings: 'id','user','product','created',etc.
```

Now I need mysql to return my most recent 10 items, either a subscription or a rating. So far, the solution found was to make two different calls:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE ... ORDER BY created LIMIT 10.
```

With the two results (20 elements), I order multidimensional array by 'created' and get the top 10 with (saving the result in $items):

```
$items = array_slice($items, 0, 10);
```

I suspect that this solution is not efficient, because I get it in two calls, and return more elemnts than I need. I've been reading that the UNION operator allows you to select several different tables at once, but with the same number of columns. My question is, what is the most efficient way to join a specific number of elements of different types ordered by a common field (created in my case) in just one call? is ot possible? Thanks a lot, any help is appreciated,
Jesús.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNION is required.

You can learn how to use it here:

[Join two tables, then Order By date, BUT combining both tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284923/join-two-tables-then-order-by-date-but-combining-both-tables)

It's not explained in the link I posted, but can put a LIMIT on a UNION as well. Combined with an ORDER BY this is what you need. (cred to Frits van Campen)

```
(SELECT cols FROM subscriptions) 
UNION 
(SELECT cols FROM ratings);
ORDER BY created LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It's not explained in the link maxhud posted, but can put a `LIMIT` on a `UNION` as well. Combined with an `ORDER BY` this is what you need.

Comment: edited. @FritsvanCampen hopefully that's okay i wrote that in there. didn't want the op to miss your comment

Comment: and what if I want to tag every result as a subscription or a rating? COuld add a field in cols like: type as 'susbscription' or type as 'rating' ?

Comment: $query = "(SELECT id,usuario,sitio,canal,tipo,created,tag as `subscription` FROM suscripciones WHERE `usuario` = '{$userid}' AND `tipo` = '0') UNION (SELECT id,user,tipo,id_objeto,valor,created,tag as `rating` FROM `puntuaciones` WHERE `user` = '{$userid}' AND `tipo` = '2') ORDER BY `created` LIMIT {$limit}";  This query is returning null. Without the tag as `...` part is ok...what am I doing wrong? thanks!!

Comment: Ok, is 'subscription' as tag or 'rating' as tag, not the other way, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query to use a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) to combine the results and once the results have been combined you can utilize the LIMIT method and ORDER BY for limiting the output to the desired number of records.

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause
>   inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:

In addition:

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION
>   result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the
>   ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one.

```
(SELECT cols FROM subscriptions WHERE ... ORDER BY created LIMIT 10) 
UNION 
(SELECT cols FROM ratings WHERE ... ORDER BY created LIMIT 10);
ORDER BY created LIMIT 10
```

Comment: but I have understood that I can only use UNION if my queries have same number of cols...is it true? in my case both tables have different cols. EDIT: in your example I get 20 elements, 10 of each table, isnt it?

Comment: That is correct, so instead of using '*' to select all columns, only select the applicable columns to get the output to match.

Comment: This code is wrong, you should move `ORDER BY created LIMIT 10` to the outside of the `UNION`. This code gives you the last 10 subscriptions and the last 10 ratings, where as OP want the last 10 'items' (subscriptions or ratings).

Comment: Actually you would keep it inside and then put it on the outside as well. The reason being is to help improve your query performance.

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance characteristics of that, I suppose it could help if MySQL does no optimization. But if MySQL is properly lazy you're actually hurting performance by always over-selecting by 10. Run an `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - I would agree.  The best method would be to run an `EXPLAIN` to verify the best route.

Comment: $query = "(SELECT id,usuario,sitio,canal,tipo,created,tag as subscription FROM suscripciones WHERE usuario = '{$userid}' AND tipo = '0') UNION (SELECT id,user,tipo,id_objeto,valor,created,tag as rating FROM puntuaciones WHERE user = '{$userid}' AND tipo = '2') ORDER BY created LIMIT {$limit}"; This query is returning null. Without the tag as ... part is ok...what am I doing wrong? thanks!!

Comment: Ok, is 'subscription' as tag or 'rating' as tag, not the other way, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html